# PHP Replace last occurence of character from current position until the end of the string

Tags: php

I have this string:

```
$string = '{"status":"2","vote":"1"},{"status":"1","vote":"0"}, "blabla"';
```

I want to get the position of the last occuring '}' and remove the rest of the characters after it and then append ']'. Please help. Thanks!

Comment: looks like a json string, how did you get this anyway?

Comment: might want to show the code which leads to this string,maybe you can work there

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
$newString = substr($string,0,(strrpos($string,"}")+1))."]";
```

strrpos gets the position of the last occurrence of a a string

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php

Answer (score 0):

You have to use PHP function `strrpos()` which will give first occurance of string from right side.

```
echo $newString = substr($string,0,strrpos($string,"}")+1)."]";
```

**Outuput**

```
{"status":"2","vote":"1"},{"status":"1","vote":"0"}]
```

Check Manual **[strrpos()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php)**

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = '{"status":"2","vote":"1"},{"status":"1","vote":"0"}, "blabla"';
$newString = (substr($string, 0, strrpos($string, "}") + 1))."]";
echo $newString; //results: {"status":"2","vote":"1"},{"status":"1","vote":"0"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the native json function,

```
$j=json_decode("[$string]");
array_pop($j);
echo json_encode($j);
```

or you will have a lot of problem like in this case:

```
 $string = '{"status":"2","vote":"1"},{"status":"1","vote":"0"}, "bla}bla"';
```